# Can you assign 3 channel image data to QCustomPlots ColorMap function?

Tags: c++, image, qt, opencv, qcustomplot

I'm working on a program for image processing. At the present stage I split a CV_64FC3 into 3 colour channels, RGB, then use this as the data for a QCPColorMap.

The implementation is like this:

```
for(int col = 0; col < image.cols; ++col) {
    for(int row = 0; row < image.rows; row++) {
          colorMap->data()->setCell(row,col,rotated_matrix.at<double>(row,col));
    }
 }
```

Where `rotated_matrix` is a CV_64FC1 cv::Mat. This works fine and displays the colour map accordingly.

My question is can I pass through a 3 channel cv::Mat `(CV_64FC3)` and assign this to the data points in the QCPColorMap?

I've had a look at the [documentation](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPColorMap.html) and as far as I can see the only variables that `colorMap->data()->setCell` or `colorMap->data()->setData` can accept are `keyIndex, valueIndex, z` which represent essentially x coordinate, y coordinate and then the colour value itself.

I can't seem to find a way to modify the number of channels/layers in the image to assign.

Am I missing something here?

Cheers
Mitch

Comment: I don't get this. Color maps are only maps of indices to a [color palette](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPColorGradient.html). Indices are by definition single values (1 channel). Why do you want them to be 3 values (3 channels)?

Comment: I have an RGB image that is going to undergo analysis, at some point the image will be split into its colour components, however I'd like that to be at a later step, not at this stage if possible.

Comment: Perhaps a more appropriate solution would be to blend to 3 channel image into a 1 channel image before applying the colour map

Comment: I have no idea of your stages... But, have you considered using [OpenCV colormaps](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html), and create your colormapped images when you want in your processing steps?

Comment: Yeah I did implement the OpenCV Colormap originally, but it has no option to show a color scale next to the image unfortunately, which I really need

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to set z value in each pixel with the value of each channel. This is not possible because z only could be one value, not three at the same time. In qcustomplot you can set 3 different graphs but again, if you set a color the same pixel is going to replace the last value set. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @ikaro yeah that's pretty much what I was hoping to do. I think I'll need to blend the 3 channels into 1 image then display as a color map

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat painful way: put multiple instances of QPColorMap over each other and use the alpha channel to toggle off selected ones. I suppose one could sub-class QPColorMap and access QRgb that way, but that would be even harder.

This does seems like a target for modification in QCustomPlot. My sample application: show a grayscale image (e.g., a brain) with a color overlay indicating either a region of interest or an "activated" or somehow abnormal area. For this one needs access to the RBG fields.